# Ghost environment setup and theme deploy

Tags: git, ghost-blog, ghost

I'm developing a theme for ghost based in another template but I'm struggling to setup Ghost locally for version control and deployment

**What I'd like to do**

- Push the changes of theme files to the remote repo
- Have my team able to clone the repo and run `npm install` and `npm start` to start seeing the latest changes of my theme on their local branch without installing Ghost every time the pull changes and without having to go into the admin panel of ghost

**What I have now**

- I pushed all Ghost files to the remote branch, including the core directory. when I try to clone the repo for testing I run `npm install --production` and `npm start` after cloning but I receive the following this:

`ERROR: Unable to populate database: The theme "casper" cannot be activated because it is not currently installed.`

Also if I don't copy the data folder to the repo then I receive this error:

`ERROR: Unable to access Ghost's content path: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myusername/folder/site/ghost/content/data'`

Comment: could you extend the question with the config.js file? I guess you have troubles with `--development` configuration

Comment: also make sure that themes are in `content/themes` before you run `npm start`. Your data problem error is within the `config.js` that attempts to load data from `content/data`. It should be there unless you properly configured an external database for the *environment* you use.